# MS CRM: After Deployment of a managed Solution a workflow is still in old version

Tags: dynamics-crm

I've deployed an update to a managed solution in CRM 2016. In this updated solution, there was an update to an existing workflow. After the deployment the workflow is still in the old version, even though the import log says that the workflow definition has been overwritten and published.

How is this possible and what can I do to make it work?

FYI: The update of the workflow was an alternation of an if expression.

Comment: Online or onpremise? This should not happen. Delete & reimport will work.

Comment: Onpremise. Delete the workflow or the managed solution, which do you mean?

Comment: deleting managed solution & reimporting will delete the component altogether & freshly creates. since yours is onprem, try this query & see whether your changes are reflecting: select SolutionId, Type, CreatedOn, * from Workflow where statecode = 1 and statuscode = 2 and Name = 'your WF name'

Comment: Did you create the managed solution yourself or is it through some external source? It can be the case that the unmanaged solution wasn't published before exporting as managed and therefore some changes are not getting transfered.

Comment: Were you able to solve your problem?

Comment: Yes we were. I've posted our solution in an answer. Thanks for your contribution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We were able to solve our problem by importing an update to the solution with the option 'step for upgrade' enabled.

I think the problem was, that we once manipulated the workflow in our managed solution over the customize system dialog. After a close inspection of the situation before the upgrade step we recognized that we had the same problem with multiple other workflows. After the upgrade step all our workflows are at the expected version.

We have to customize some of our workflows at the production environment because some of them have email tasks inside of them in which we want the email to be from a team. This team unfortunately has an other id on the developing environment than on the production environment.

Answer (score 0):

Delete the managed solution from target environment. Retry by exporting a new managed solution from source environment (after publish all) & import in target, then publish all.

Since yours is onprem, run this query & compare the result with both environments.

```
select SolutionId, Type, CreatedOn, * from Workflow where statecode = 1 and statuscode = 2 and Name = 'your WF name'
```

For every version of Workflow, this table will have one entry, the old versions will have different combo of `statecode` & `statuscode`